# Interprocess notification replacement using dbus-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbus, libnotify, dbus-python

I'm trying to set up notifications for brightness controls that are replaced immediately when a new notification is sent. I've managed to create a test to get this working within the same python process/script but if a new process is run the notification is not replaced.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dbus
import sys
import os
import time

item = 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
path = '/org/freedesktop/Notifications'
interface = 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
app_name = 'dbus test'
title = 'dbus test'
timeout = 5000   # Use seconds x 1000

notify_id_file = '/tmp/dbus-id-{}'.format(os.getenv('USER'))

try:
    with open(notify_id_file, 'r') as f:
        notify_id = dbus.UInt32(f.read())
except:
    notify_id = dbus.UInt32(0)

icon = '/home/shane/.icons/Surfn/32/notifications/notification-display-brightness-full.svg'
hint = {'type': 'int', 'name': 'value', 'value': int(sys.argv[1])}

bus = dbus.SessionBus(private=False)
notif = bus.get_object(item, path)
notify = dbus.Interface(notif, interface)

notify_id = notify.Notify(app_name, notify_id, icon, title, '', '', hint, timeout)

with open(notify_id_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(notify_id))

# Emulating second call, works from within same process, not from another

time.sleep(1)


bus = dbus.SessionBus(private=False)
notif = bus.get_object(item, path)
notify = dbus.Interface(notif, interface)

with open(notify_id_file, 'r') as f:
    notify_id = dbus.UInt32(f.read())

hint = {'type': 'int', 'name': 'value', 'value': int(sys.argv[1]) + 20}

notify_id = notify.Notify(app_name, notify_id, icon, title, '', '', hint, timeout)

with open(notify_id_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(notify_id))
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, especially seeing as it all works within the same process. It's almost like dbus isn't actually communicating across processes but the process has its own private connection or something?

Just in case it's important, I'm using:

- python 3.6.4
- dbus 1.12.4
- python-dbus 1.2.6
- notify-osd 0.9.35 (using the customizable leolik branch)

and this is all under i3 on arch linux.

Comment: Please format the code within the post instead of a link.

Comment: @Cole done that now, thought maybe it wasn't a good idea since it's a fairly long script. Forgot that stackoverflow scrolls the code blocks.